# Attaching more than one feeds url to a single content type

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I have a feeds setup in which i have a content type discount travels.I have created a feeds import using xpath xml parser.Now i want to attach one more link to the same content type.I know currently there is no provision for this in the feeds module.Instead we can create one more new feed importer with new link and attach it to the same content type.I doubt is it possible to have 2 unique fileds in the same content type.I have mapped one field from first URL to guid and marked it as unique.Then i mapped another field from second URL to guid and marked it as unique.Then i attached the new import to the same discount travels content type.Has anybody achieved this before using feeds and feeds import.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the GUID field method that comes with Feeds, it is possible to use Feeds with the [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module. See the discussion at patch at the bottom of [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/661606#comment-6288870).

I haven't tried it, but Field Validation might let you set multiple unique fields as it provides validation options for every field in a content type.